# Rails Console commands won't work. Terminal also acts up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I'm having trouble with the rails console in terminal. I run Ubuntu 14.04, rails 4.2, and ruby 2.0.0.

Anyway, when I start up rails console, it loads the development environment. Then I try to create a new object with `things = article.new` and I get an error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'article' for main:Object
from /home/roonie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-     
4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /home/roonie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-
4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/roonie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-
4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /home/roonie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-
4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
```

This keeps going on for like 40 more lines.

The `Article` class exists btw in my`ArticlesController.rb` file. Also I'm working in the directory of my project when I start up rails console so that can't be the issue. I'm new to ruby and rails so I just have no idea how to fix this.

My terminal also acts up after I exit rails console following this error. I'll type a simple `-ls` command and it'll give me the same errors I was just getting. I don't get that: `-ls` isn't even a ruby command! And then, I'll get even weirder errors from my terminal. For instance, I'll just type `rails --version` and it'll give me this:

> The program 'al' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>       sudo apt-get install mono-devel

Comment: Try

    `thing = Article.new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes in Ruby have a capital first letter by convention, so to create a new instance of a class you need to use:

```
instance = Class.new
```

NOT: `instance = class.new`

In your case:

```
things = Article.new
```

Comment: Thanks I'should have realized that was the mistake. Any idea why terminal completely poops out once I make that error though? Like why would that error cause terminal to think that when I type "-ls", that I typed "hn" or some nonsensical thing. Or why would I get that error msg at the bottom of my post?

Comment: Are you sure you're in a normal terminal (`bash`) when you enter that?

Comment: hmm what else might I be in? Is there a command I can enter to verify I'm using a bash shell

Comment: Well if you're in the rails console then you can't enter bash commands. Check what the prompt says.

Comment: well i intentionally recreated that error and then i typed ctrl+c to exit the rails console. Then, I see the normal prompt prior to where you enter unix comments: name@name:~/path/to/project$

So then i entered ls to try it out and I get those same error messages, and the prompt now reads: 

from -e:1:in `<main>'2.0.0-p598 :004 >

Comment: Sorry, not sure. Although I think to  exit the rails console you have to `exit` not just `control-C`.